# ReactJS - net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm suddenly having issues with production versions of my react apps. They work fine in development, however when I build them, I get a console error:

/static/css/main.f6418f8a.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> 1.13eeb203.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> main.1e6014ca.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> /favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

This error was received after the following commands:

`create-react-app whatiswrong`

`npm run build`

Then open the index.html in my browser like I would for any other react apps I've built.

Comment: are you running `npm run build` inside the `whatiswrong` folder?

Comment: @vencovsky - Yes I am. I have tried building multiple new projects with create-react-app and I get the same.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to add `"homepage": "./"` to your package.json.

From:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6275#issuecomment-457813277

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your package.json file.
2. Add this entry to it `"homepage":"path\to\your\project\build\"`
3. Re-run the command `npm run build`.

> The issue here was when you run the npm run build command without the homepage entry added in your package.json,it is built assuming that the project directory (where you are running the command) is hosted at server root.

[screen-shot commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahAHy.png)

```
D:\git_repo\my-app>npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build D:\git_repo\my-app
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  44.57 KB  build\static\js\main.8a29685f.js

**The project was built assuming it is hosted at root directory.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.**

The build folder is ready to be deployed.


D:\git_repo\my-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your app? Are you just opening the index.html in the browser or are you using `serve -s build` and such?

If you are doing it by the first option then you should consider trying `serve -s build`